# Effective dielectric constant in multilayer PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, rf, pcb-layers, dielectric, dielectric-breakdown

- Top => copper
- PP1 => RO4350B
- L2 => copper
- PP2 => FR4
- L3 => copper
- PP3 => 185HR
- L4 => copper

This is my PCB stackup.

In the top layer, I have a 50 Ω controlled RF trace.  The bottom reference of the trace is in L3.

I have a cutout under the trace on L2 to maintain the 50 ohm impedance to the reference L3.

Between top to L3, there are two different dielectrics with different Dk (pp1=3.66, pp2=4.4.)

What will be the effective dielectric constant for the RF trace to L3? How can I calculate it?

Comment: Welcome! Please write to the best of your ability, this includes not shouting in the title, capitalize the first letter of every sentence and run your text though a spellcheck.

Comment: Why do you have that topology? If you need the Rogers material, why not have it all the way through, or have your reference layer on L2?

Answer (score 1):

If you have vertically stacked dielectrics then this effectively forms two capacitors in series: One with \$\epsilon_r=3.66\$, and the other with \$\epsilon_r=4.4\$.

If the thicknesses are equal then the effective dielectric constant will be

$$
\epsilon=2 \ \frac{\epsilon_{r1} \ \epsilon_{r2}}{\epsilon_{r1} + \epsilon_{r2}}
$$

If the thicknesses are different then you need to work out from

$$
C =\epsilon_r \ \epsilon \frac{A}{d}
$$

for each dielectric and its thickness, and

$$
\frac{1}{C}=\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}
$$

to obtain the final dielectric constant.

Comment: But there's no conductor (plate) between the two dielectrics.  So I don't think this is equivalent to two capacitors in series.

Comment: @SteveSh you don't need a plate in between because it's all about the E-fields. Imagine a capacitor with two plates with surface area of A, one is attached to 0V and the other is attached to some voltage. Now work out the E-fields at some distances (d1 and d2, let's say) i.e. use \$E = V/d = q / (\epsilon \ A)\$ and \$q = C \ V\$, and you'll find that it works like two series-connected capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

If your stackup/trace impedance tool can't handle that topology, I would just calculate an average Dk based on the thickness and Dk of the two materials.